# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CloudFlare' in Python

Tags: python

Hi i have a problem with Python module not found here, i decided to posting here cause i confuse with the error message

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CloudFlare'`

i already run `pip install cloudflare`

https://prnt.sc/GtXZE5xiPrIZ

the error is the same, but when i check the `import CloudFlare` package its shown that its connected to the module

https://prnt.sc/BorGtl5hCK8i

is there any problem when my file is not in the "laragon file" cause the pip is attach to laragon system ?

edit :

My python version is `Python 3.12.0` its windows 7

Comment: _My python version is Python 3.12.0_ Well, that's the problem.  pip installed the module for python 3.10, not 3.12.

Comment: thanks man i already solve the problem but its gonna be hard without @alexis comment, i tryna figure it out rn for the python version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not using the same python version in your IDE and in your console.
Check which version you're IDE is using, and check with `which python3` or `which python` in your console if they are the same.

If not, use the correct pip in your console or change your python version in the IDE.

Comment: yeah i checked my python version right now its different i tryna fix the problem right now thanks for the advice